# Use of the "&" symbol

Tags: conjunctions, ampersand

When is it academically correct to use "&" (an ampersand)?
In university standard writing can you always use "&" instead of the word "and"?

Comment: FWIW The ampersand is a typographic symbol, **also** used in the English language; it's not (owned by) the English (BrE or AmE or other) language. This question is like asking if I should prefer *etc.,* or *and so on and so forth.* Style guides have their reasons for deprecating the ampersand sign or recommending limited use. User discretion is recommended at all times.

Comment: @Ronan *et al.* I find the accepted answer at the linked "original question" to be unsatisfactory/ unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Style manuals typically recommend the use of "and" rather than "&" in running text. Exceptions are made for common abbreviations such as the name of a corporation, and stylistic typography in general, most commonly title pages, particularly for ceremonial purposes such as a dissertation. Tradition trumps brevity in most of the contexts, however.

See [this FAQ](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Ampersands.html) on the Chicago Manual of Style website.

> CMOS 14 regards ampersands as abbreviations that may be changed to
>   “and” in running text. Exceptions include expressions like “R&D” and
>   names of corporations that are generally abbreviated, such as AT&T,
>   where it would be odd to spell out “and” but not the rest of the
>   abbreviation.
>
> [A couple of decades and a few administrations later:] The sixteenth
>   edition would side with your author. If a company appears to prefer an
>   ampersand in its name, then write it that way (e.g., Marks & Spencer).
>   If in doubt, you can spell it out. Be consistent.

Comment: And some referencing styles require it for dual author references, but that's very different from using it in the main text.

Comment: How does this address acceptable _academic_ standards? Universities have their own requirements (and style guides).

Answer (score 0):

It is generally good practise to refrain from abbreviation in exams and assignments, indeed some exam criterion specifically state to not abbreviate.

Just write out *and* in full, it doesn't take all that much longer.

Comment: That's an opinion.

Comment: That's ungrammatical.

Comment: @Kris - no, I have been marked down before in an exam for abbreviating.